# Error en Apache de Xampp

Tags: xampp

> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked
>   port, missing dependencies,  improper privileges, a crash, or a
>   shutdown by another method. press the Logs button to view error logs
>   and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues if you need more
>   help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums

Comment: Muestranos el log, solo debes presionar el boton de "Logs" en apache

Comment: puede que tengas puertos ocupados cámbialos en (httpd.conf) desde el boton config

Answer (score 1):

!Buenas!

Este error proviene de un problema con los puertos. Así que haz una cosa:

Abre **XAMP**, y ve a **CONFIG**.

Entra en **Service and Ports Settings**. Y en el recuadro de **Main Port** cambia el puerto por **82**. Y en **SSL PORT** lo cambias por **4432** ( Estos puertos son ejemplos, la intención es quitar los de defecto). Guardas y vas cerrando las pestañas.

Ahora posicionate en Apache, y presiona **conf** y ve al archivo **httpd.conf** y abrelo. En este, busca entre todo el texto: **"Listen"**. Y cambia ese puerto por el anteriormente introducido, el **82**, creo recordar que en este archivo hay dos **listen**. Guarda y cierra.

Ahora hacemos lo mismo, pero abre el archivo **httpd-ssl.conf**. Buscas lo mismo, **Listen** y vuelve a cambiar el valor por el otro, el **4432**. Guardas y cierra.

Con esto el problema debe de estar resuelto, me paso hace tiempo lo mismo y lo solucione así.

*Por cierto, si los puertos te siguen dando problemas, cámbialos por otros. Puede que estén ocupados.*

Un saludo.